# How to get value from any HTML tag in php variable?

Tags: php, jquery, html

what I am asking is

I have some value in `<p>`

eg. `<p>Hello</p>`

now I want to know  is there any way to get the value inside `<p>` in a PHP variable  `$getPara`

(in session variable or normal variable or global variable)

so that when I write `<strong><?php echo $getPara; ?></strong>` then it will print **Hello**

Comment: please revise, this question is rather vague.

Comment: Funnily enough, in IE6, it will send the innerHTML of a button element when submitted.

Comment: funnily?? lol :=) is that a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look for any element having `.includeMe` as a class name, and create a  form element for it. The next time the form is sent, those items will be sent as values too:

```
<p class="includeMe" id="state">Georgia</p>
```

--

```
$(function(){
  // Everything with class 'includeMe'
  $(".includeMe").each(function(){
    var id   = $(this).attr("id"),
        text = $(this).text(),
        elem = $("<input type='hidden'/>").attr("id", id).val(text);
    // Add to form
    $("form").append(elem);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

The browser will submit all form fields (`input`, `select`, and `textarea`) to the server, but it won't send any other data.

You need to use Javascript.

Comment: +1. The PHP script runs server-side and generates the HTML, Javascript runs client-side and reads/manipulates the PHP-generated HTML. It seems to me as if you want to do a Javascript trick in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is with input specifically, then you can use

```
<textarea name="some_name_to_use_in_php">hello</textarea>
```